# Inaccessible cardinals and the perfect set property for coanalytic sets

Tags: reference-request, set-theory, large-cardinals, descriptive-set-theory, constructibility

I am wondering who proved the following fact:

($\ast$) If $\omega_1$ is not inaccessible in $L$, then there is an uncountable coanalytic set of reals without a perfect subset.

I have been unable to track down a reference for it.
All I found so far is:

1. In the 1930s, Gödel proved that if $V = L$, then there is an uncountable coanalytic set of reals without a perfect subset.
2. In 1957, Specker proved in $\mathsf{ZF}$ that if $\omega_1$ is regular in $V$ but not inaccessible in $L$, then there is an uncountable set of reals without a perfect subset.

Someone recently said to me that ($\ast$) should be credited to Gödel, but on the other hand the fact that the much later [paper](http://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/10.1002/malq.19570031302/full) of Specker is cited for the weaker result (2) suggests to me that ($\ast$) should not be considered to follow immediately from Gödel's work.  I don't read German, so I can't tell if Specker actually proved ($\ast$).

Edit:  When I say that (2) is weaker than ($\ast$), I am thinking of ($\ast$) as being proved in the theory $\mathsf{ZF} + {}$"$\omega_1$ is regular in $V$."  (It seems to me that any reasonable proof in $\mathsf{ZFC}$ would also work in this context, because $\mathsf{AC}$ does not seem relevant for constructing coanalytic sets.)

Comment: From the discussion in Kanamori "The Higher Infinite" page 135, I get the impression that Specker's advancement was the use of an inner model to show that the perfect set property for all boldface $\Pi_1^1$ sets imply the consistency of an inacccessible cardinal.

Comment: Although I do not know Godel specific example of a thin $\Pi_1^1$ set; however, it probably involved some coding of $L_\alpha$ for $\alpha < \omega_1^L$ by reals. Surely this can be relativized to coding $L_\alpha[x]$ for $\alpha < \omega_1^{L[x]}$ and yield a thin uncountable $\Pi_1^1(x)$ set assuming $\omega_1^{L[x]} = \omega_1^V$. It is likely Godel method could relative to prove (*); however, whether he was aware of enough of these notions for credit is another issue.

Comment: @William Unless I'm missing something, that passage from Kanamori doesn't mention $\Pi^1_1$ sets.  Regarding your second comment, I agree that Gödel's argument probably relativizes to any real. The argument I have in mind certainly does.  However, depending on what argument Gödel used, more work might be necessary to show that the set it constructs does not contain a perfect set *in $V$*.  I don't know if he did this.

Comment: Nowadays, we think of relativization as a trivial step; if you prove a theorem about $L$ and I point out that it also holds for $L[x]$ for any real $x$, I'm not really making any progress. But things were different in the old days; relativization could be real progress. For example, I vaguely recall reading somewhere that the relative consistency result "if  ZFC + $V\neq L$ is consistent then it remains consistent if you adjoin CH" was not explicitly proved before 1950.

Comment: The result is not literally Gödel's, although of course nowadays we see it as essentially the same proof as item 1. The reason is that the $L[x]$ models had not been considered until Lévy's work, from 1957, and item 1 itself did not see a proof in print until Novikov's work from 1951 (in Russian) and Addison's in 1959. After 1959 the result would have been noticed pretty quickly, but I do not know who mentioned it first. Maybe asking Addison may clarify this point.

Comment: I vaguely recall some relevant (or semi-relevant) results in Ioanna Dimitriou's masters thesis.

Comment: Trevor, you are misstating Specker's result: that there are uncountable sets without a perfect subset was proved back in 1908, by Bernstein. What Specker did was to prove *in $\mathsf{ZF}$* that if $\aleph_1$ is regular in ${\mathrm V}$ but not inaccessible in $L$, then there are uncountable sets of reals without a perfect subset. The point, of course, is that choice is not involved in the argument. (That $\aleph_1$ is regular also ends up being important, but that's a different story.)

Comment: @Andrés Oops, you are right.  I was thinking of the hypothesis as $\mathsf{ZF} + \mathsf{DC}$, but didn't write it.  Anyway, I will edit the question to state the correct hypothesis $\mathsf{ZF} + {}$"$\aleph_1$ is regular."

Comment: OK, yet another wrinkle to the story: I looked at Specker's paper. There is no descriptive set theory there. What he shows is that if $\aleph_1$ is regular and there is no function picking an enumeration of each countable ordinal, then $\aleph_1$ is inaccessible in $L$. The connection with perfect sets is actually due to Mycielski in his 1964 paper on determinacy. I think it requires creative reading to attribute 2. to Specker. Even the wording in Mycielski's paper does not make 2. explicit. (And neither paper is particularly easy to read due to how they are organized, and their notation.)

Comment: I mean, if one is going to go as far as to attribute 2. to Specker, then one would obviously attribute $(*)$ to Gödel. Neither attribution is accurate.

Comment: @Andrés  Thanks for the correction.  I was following Kanamori in attributing (2) to Specker.  I will take a look at Mycielski's paper.